# App Service not able to connect to resources through VPN Connection

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network

I've got a Web API (.NET Core 3.1) running on an App Service and I am not able to send data to an external API present on another server outside Azure.

The Virtual Network Gateway is assigned with the VNet and 2 external Connections and both are working well (status Connected). I can ping services and access the resources from the office.

The VPN Connection is a **Site-to-Site** VPN in the same VNet. It is working fine and I can send the data **if I run my API on a VM in Azure**.

Looks like the App Service cannot see the network in the same way the VM does.

What should I do to get the App Service to be able to utilise the VPN Connection?

Comment: "Looks like the App Service cannot see the network in the same way the VM does. " Could you clarify it for more details? Can you use `tcpping private IP of on-premise resource:port` from the app service--console https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-networking-options#tools?

Comment: I am back to this issue. No, I tried to ping from the appservice - console and is "Unable to contact IP driver"

Comment: It's all working now. VNet integration wasn't configured and I have also set the `WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL` to `1`. Thanks

Comment: Also tried `tcpping IP_SERVER:PORT` and got a successful response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to app service access resources in on-premise network, I supposed you have [integrated you app with an Azure virtual network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet) and set up Site-to-Site VPN in the same VNet.

Make sure that you have set the app setting `WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL` to `1`

> When regional VNet Integration is enabled, your app makes outbound
> calls to the internet through the same channels as normal. The
> outbound addresses that are listed in the app properties portal are
> the addresses still used by your app. What changes for your app are
> the calls to service endpoint secured services, or RFC 1918 addresses
> go into your VNet. If `WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL` is set to `1`, all
> outbound traffic can be sent into your VNet.
>
> WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL is currently not supported in Windows
> containers.

Comment: VNET integration wasn't configured and the AppSetting was also missing. All fine now. Thanks